# Как проверять в редиректе REQUEST массив?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Есть задача сделать редирект с https://www.site.ru/some/category/another/mayby/?position=mine на страницу типу https://www.site.ru/some/?position=mine 
То-есть, между `some` и реквест запросом может быть любые произв. папки, главное чтобы в конце был конкретный Реквест запрос и начало тоже было равно `some`. Никак не получаеться, уже час бью голову. Буду благодарен за совет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
# в get параметрах запроса есть position равный mine
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bposition=mine\b
# в адреса запроса some/ стоит в начале и после слеша есть символы 
RewriteRule ^some/.+ https://www.site.ru/some/ [R=301,L,QSA]
```